# [SQL/DQL]How to Filter with a IN acting as 'and' and not 'or'

Tags: php, sql, symfony, easyadmin

It's hard to describe what I'm trying to do but I 'll do my my best.

I want to filter an Association and I use EntityFilter for that, this association can have multiple value :
[image]

For my example, I'm looking for a person who is `illustrateur/dessinateur` and `Animateur/intervenant`.

In my index Crud I have 3 persons, one with no activities, one with both activities illustrateur/dessinateur`and`Animateur/intervenant`and on with only one activity`Animateur/intervenant`.

[image]

Now if I filter with both activities, 2 peoples are showing and it's not the behavior I want :

[image]

I only want `Farrah` because it's the only one who's got the 2 activities.

Then I looked in EntityFilter and I have notices they use the class orX :

```php
if ($entityDto->isToManyAssociation($property)) {
            // the 'ea_' prefix is needed to avoid errors when using reserved words as assocAlias ('order', 'group', etc.)
            // see https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/pull/4344
            $assocAlias = 'ea_'.$filterDataDto->getParameterName();
            $queryBuilder->leftJoin(sprintf('%s.%s', $alias, $property), $assocAlias);

            if (0 === \count($value)) {
                $queryBuilder->andWhere(sprintf('%s %s', $assocAlias, $comparison));
            } else {
                $orX = new Orx();
                $orX->add(sprintf('%s %s (:%s)', $assocAlias, $comparison, $parameterName));
                if ('NOT IN' === $comparison) {
                    $orX->add(sprintf('%s IS NULL', $assocAlias));
                }
                $queryBuilder->andWhere($orX)
                    ->setParameter($parameterName, $this->processParameterValue($queryBuilder, $value));
            }
```

Then I overided this filter and replaced `Orx` by `AndX` but still the same result :(

And then I tried this :

```php
foreach ($value as $item) {
    if ($comparison === 'NOT IN') {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn($assocAlias, [$item->getId()]));
    } else {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->in($assocAlias, [$item->getId()]));
    } 
}
```

But `IN` act as the `OR` and I would like a strict if. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Doing a custom filter would probably be your best bet

Comment: This is what I'm doing and I'm using `IN` as you can see in my foreach but I want `In`act like `AND` and not `OR`

Comment: `in` is meant to be or - there is no way around that.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without `IN` ?